# Fiware IDM Keystone on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, fiware

I've tried to install FIWARE IDM - Keystone on my own server (Ubuntu 14.04). Everything went well till when I tried to populate the database using the following command

```
fab localhost keystone.populate
```

where python sent the following error

```
[localhost] Executing task 'keystone.populate'
Created Services and Endpoints
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/main.py", line 743, in main
    *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 384, in execute
    multiprocessing
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fabric/tasks.py", line 274, in _execute
    return task.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/juan/idm/deployment/keystone.py", line 248, in run
    self._create_endpoint_group_filters(keystone)
  File "/home/juan/idm/deployment/keystone.py", line 285, in _create_endpoint_group_filters
    regions = keystone.regions.list()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystoneclient/httpclient.py", line 620, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Unknown Attribute: %s" % name)
AttributeError: Unknown Attribute: regions
```

Same command was executed in Ubuntu 12.05 and worked well. Is there any known confict in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: there is no known issue that affects Ubuntu 14.04 that I am aware of, I have installed always in Ubuntu 14 with no issues. I'll take a look into it, seems to be some problem with the python client

Answer (score 0):

I just saw how old this question is. I think it was a specific issue with that installation/environment in particular because there are no know issues with Ubuntu 14.04 and the IdM has always been deployed in that version.

Using the latest release should work correctly in Ubuntu 14.04.